# Cannot plot chart using D3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm learning how to plot charts using D3.js on SVG objects.
My code creates elements in DOM objects, but they do not display.
If I run DOM inspector and copy all elements to another html document and display that the rectangles are visible.

I'm trying to plot two static rectangles on [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/6x7khgz7/2/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG is case sensitive so you want

```
svg = d3.select("div#Wykres2")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", szerokosc)
    .attr("height", wysokosc)
    .text("not work :(");
```